# Numerical Recipes for Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, numerical-methods

I was dusting off my copy of [Numerical Recipes in C book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431085) and started wondering if a similar treatment exists for algorithms that can be palatalized using MapReduce and Hadoop.

Thanks.

Comment: Someone voted for this question to be closed using the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice compilation from [atbrox](http://atbrox.com/2011/11/09/mapreduce-hadoop-algorithms-in-academic-papers-5th-update-%E2%80%93-nov-2011/) for the different algorithms in different domains. For text processing [here](http://lintool.github.com/MapReduceAlgorithms/index.html) is nice one another. Also, search @ [CiteSeerx](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/index).